# Mapping ViewModel to Model with automapper

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a trouble in Automapper with this Model

```
public class Contact 
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string MessageTitle { get; set; }
        public string MessageBody { get; set; }
        public string MessageTime { get; set; }
    }
```

and this ViewModel

```
 public class ContactView
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string MessageTitle { get; set; }
        public string MessageBody { get; set; }
        public string MessageTime { get; set; }
    }
```

and this is my converting Methods :

```
//Convert to Model
    public static Contact ConvertToContactModel(this ContactView contactView)
    {
        return Mapper.Map<ContactView, Contact>(contactView);

    }


 //Convert to ViewModel
     public static ContactView ConvertToContactView(this Contact contact)
            {
                return Mapper.Map<Contact, ContactView>(contact);
            }
```

why convert to Model (ConvertToContactModel) method doesn't work ??

Comment: **doesn't work** is not that clear... (still not clear : what do you mean by doesn't work ? Error thrown, result is not what you want ?)

Comment: Have you created the map first? `Mapper.CreateMap<ContactView, Contact>()` and vice-versa?

Comment: Didn't Got ur mean , I've mapping methods in separate class with this calling :  public void CreateContact(CreateContactRequest request)
        {
            ContactView contact = new ContactView();
            Contact modelContact = contact.ConvertToContactModel();
            _contactRepository.Add(modelContact);
            _unitOfWork.Commit();

        }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you create mappings **before** mapping some objects. You should have this code on application start (`Main` method, or `Application_Start` in *Global.asax*):

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ContactView, Contact>();
Mapper.CreateMap<Contact, ContactView>();
```